# React tates not updating in IE

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

Basically, whats happening is that everything works fine in chrome, and IE works locally with npm start, however, when i build, none of my states are updated when doing tasks such as clicking buttons, dragging sliders etc. I have looked at similar problems, but stuff like adding X polyfill has not worked for me. If any more info is needed i will try to answer to the best of my abilities.

I'm sorry for the vague question, but due to this being work-related, i'm not allowed to share code. Ideally i would like to ask colleagues, but they are all too busy, and i've been stuck for a while.

Comment: If you can't show your code, don't ask on StackOverflow. You should bug your coworkers again.

Comment: You're going to have to share a minimal example of that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I very much understand that, and apologize for the inconvenience. I'm still new, so i'm sadly not aware of what components would be needed to create a generalized example for stackoverflow. Thanks for replying, and i apologize again...

Comment: @malikaasen try reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for info on how to create a minimal, reproducible example. Doing that will also help you debug your problem.

Comment: I'm just gonna close this one. I finally managed to find out the issue. The library i used supported onClick and on_click etc locally apparently, but when built, on_click is required for IE11. This never showed up in any of the debugging tools or logs, hence i thought the issue lied elswhere. Thanks for taking the time to at least educate me on how to make better posts in the future!

Comment: From your last comment, I can see that you have solved the issue. I suggest that you can put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. Or you can close it as you wish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to find out the issue. The library i used supported onClick and on_click etc locally apparently, but when built, on_click is required for IE11. This never showed up in any of the debugging tools or logs, hence i thought the issue lied elswhere.